# How to call vetoableChange?

Tags: java

I have one problem, method `fireVetoableChange()` didn't call `vetoableChange()`
There is example of my code.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.beans.VetoableChangeListener;
import java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestVetoable {
    private int x;
    private final VetoableChangeSupport vcs;

    public TestVetoable(){
        vcs = new VetoableChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public void addVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener listener) {
             vcs.addVetoableChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener listener) {
             vcs.removeVetoableChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int newX){
        try{
            vcs.fireVetoableChange("x", x, newX);
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some phrase");
        }
        x = newX;
    }

    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("x")){
            if ((Integer) evt.getOldValue() > (Integer) evt.getNewValue()){
                throw new PropertyVetoException("Again some phrase", evt);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've added it for you in this case, but its perfectly acceptable (and preferable) to simply put the code directly in the question. Saves us from having to go to another page.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried, but Ctrl+V option and ordinary mouse 'Paste' didn't paste it :)

Comment: @mdewitt Its a method of the [`VetoableChangeSupport` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/VetoableChangeSupport.html). They're invoking it in their `setX` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to listen to vetoable change events, you need to add a listener. Just putting the method in your JavaBean won't work. To make it work, you can create a listener class:

```
public class MyVetoableChangeListener {
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And then add a listener to your bean somewhere else:

```
test.addVetoableChangeListener(new MyVetoableChangeListener());
```

Or you can shorten things up with an inner class:

```
test.addVetoableChangeListener(new VetoableChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
        // do something
    }
});
```